# Error al obtener Location cuando inicio la APP

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocalización

Cuando ingreso a la app me surge un error con la obtención de la localización de mi usuario... Este es el error que surge en el logcat:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
    at apps.tonum.tonum.Fragment.LookingServiceFragment.locationStart(LookingServiceFragment.java:824)
    at apps.tonum.tonum.Fragment.LookingServiceFragment.onCreateView(LookingServiceFragment.java:178)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Y este es el código donde surge el error, primero llamo a la función locationStart(), dentro de esta función se genera el error, en la siguiente línea de código:

```
city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
```

Y este es el código completo de la función:

```
private void locationStart() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1000);
        return;
    }

    gps = new GPSTracker(getContext());
    double curlat=gps.getLatitude();
    double curlon=gps.getLongitude();
    LatLng currentmepos=new LatLng(curlat, curlon);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(currentmepos.latitude, currentmepos.longitude, 1);
        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Mi ciudad es " + city + '\n' + "Mi país es " + country, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (city != null && country != null) {
            ps = country;
            cdad = city;
        } else {
            ps = "País";
            cdad = "Ciudad";
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

He intentado solucionarlo de diversas maneras, pero sigue dando el mismo error... No sé cómo solucionarlo, espero puedan ayudarme. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Claramente **addresses** es una lista vacía. Revisa por qué *geocoder.getFromLocation(...)* no devuelve datos.

Comment: Según la documentación el el método geocoder.getFromLocation puede retornar null si los parámetros enviados no coinciden con algún valor que pueda ser retornado, deberías revisar que parámetros envías y validar que son correctos para las variables  curlat y curlon.

Comment: para no confundir el método puede retornar (vació o null) y en tu caso te retorna vació, el objeto addresses esta vació y al hacer get(0) intentas obtener una posición de la lista que no existe y eso provoca el java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0, porque recuerda que la posición 0 (index 0) es el primer elemento en lista y si el tamaño de la lista es 0 (size is 0)  no posee ningún elemento.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran eso debe ser, el problema es que a veces si funciona y me indica el lugar donde estoy, podría trabajar con un if de alguna manera para que cuando no obtenga el valor me deje trabajar sin la geolocalización y no me de ese error?, porque en este momento me genera ese error y me bota de la aplicación.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev conoces alguna forma de solucionar ese problema con un IF, de manera que se salte ese error si es que existe? Porque hay veces que sí me detecta el lugar donde estoy, pero otras veces no...

Comment: **if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) { ... }**

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev eso era lo que me faltaba, lo estaba evaluando con el != null solamente, pero ahora con el size() > 0 se me solucionó el problema por completo. Muchas gracias, que tengas buen día.

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas debes tener en cuenta que no todos los puntos que definas con Geocoder puede  tener información, en estos casos la longitud del array es 0, por esta razón tienes que validar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando Geocoder no garantiza que al definir valores de latitud o longitud obtengas objetos Address, ya que algunos puntos de geolocalizacion no tienen registrada esta información.

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
```

Lo que debes realizar es validar el caso en el cual no se obtenga información:

```
if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) { 

  String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); 
  String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
  String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
  String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
  String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
  String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();

}
```

No estoy seguro si en algún caso devuelve null y sea necesario validarlo ya que de acuerdo a la descripción del método siempre devuelve un array conteniendo las direcciones.

> **getFromLocation()** Devuelve un arreglo de direcciones que se sabe que
>   describen el área que rodea inmediatamente la latitud y longitud dadas

Comment: No entiendo por qué publicas esta respuesta si no aporta nada. Todo lo que tu pones ya está en los comentarios de arriba que se han escrito mucho antes. A ver si te dan algún puntito más...

Comment: Las preguntas no se responden con comentarios por eso esta respuesta que aclara el problema, Eugenio Enchiv, te sugiero revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Sé como responder, no hace falta que me redirijas al how-to. Y se responde cuando tienes algo que aportar y tu no aportas nada. Además no es la primera vez que haces esto. Y, por favor, escribe mi nombre bien, tampoco cuesta tanto copiar.

Comment: No es la primera vez? , dame otro ejemplo en el cual no aporto, tal vez pueda modificar mi respuesta en esa respuesta =)